# Migrading from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014 (between servers)

Tags: migration, sql-server

How do I move a SharePoint database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014.  Do I have to do an in-place SQL upgrade on SQL 2008 to SQL 2014, then move the database onto the new server?  Thank you!

Comment: Is it related to sharepoint SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do an inplace upgrade for SQL Server. That said, do keep in mind that SharePoint 2010 is only compatible with up to SQL Server 2012. SharePoint 2013 supports SQL 2014 with the May 2014 CU.